# Dynamic Rowspan creation for HTML Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Question:** Looking for Jquery or javascript solution to create dynamic table along with Rowspan. I am facing issue to get the parent row and add the rowspan.

your help is much appreciated.

Here is my JSON format

```
 {"nodes":[{"data":"All","nodes":[{"data":"Incident Management","nodes":[{"data":"Global","nodes":[{"data":"Bangalore","nodes":[{"data":"85.00%","nodes":[{"data":"90.00%","nodes":[{"data":"test","nodes":null}]}]},{"data":"90.00%","nodes":[{"data":"95.00%","nodes":[{"data":"test","nodes":null}]}]}]},{"data":"Frimley","nodes":[{"data":"85.00%","nodes":[{"data":"90.00%","nodes":[{"data":"test","nodes":null}]}]},{"data":"90.00%","nodes":[{"data":"95.00%","nodes":[{"data":"test","nodes":null}]}]}]},{"data":"Palo Alto","nodes":[{"data":"85.00%","nodes":[{"data":"90.00%","nodes":[{"data":"test","nodes":null}]}]},{"data":"90.00%","nodes":[{"data":"95.00%","nodes":[{"data":"test","nodes":null}]}]}]}]}]},{"data":"Service Availability","nodes":[{"data":"Global","nodes":[{"data":"N/A","nodes":[{"data":"85.00%","nodes":[{"data":"90.00%","nodes":[{"data":"","nodes":null}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve

[table look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97yX0.png)

HTML

```
<table>
  <tbody>
<tr class="odd">
  <td rowspan="7">All</td>
  <td rowspan="6">Incident Management</td>
  <td rowspan="6">Global</td>
  <td rowspan="2">Bangalore</td>
  <td rowspan="1">85.00%</td>
  <td rowspan="1">90.00%</td>
  <td rowspan="1">test</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
  <td rowspan="1">90.00%</td>
  <td rowspan="1">95.00%</td>
  <td rowspan="1">test</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
  <td rowspan="2">Frimley</td>
  <td rowspan="1">85.00%</td>
  <td rowspan="1">90.00%</td>
  <td rowspan="1">test</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
  <td rowspan="1">90.00%</td>
  <td rowspan="1">95.00%</td>
  <td rowspan="1">test</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
  <td rowspan="2">Palo Alto</td>
  <td rowspan="1">85.00%</td>
  <td rowspan="1">90.00%</td>
  <td rowspan="1">test</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
  <td rowspan="1">90.00%</td>
  <td rowspan="1">95.00%</td>
  <td rowspan="1">test</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
  <td rowspan="1">Service Availability</td>
  <td rowspan="1">Global</td>
  <td rowspan="1">N/A</td>
  <td rowspan="1">85.00%</td>
  <td rowspan="1">90.00%</td>
  <td rowspan="1">test</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: so you are trying to create a table based on the JSON you got. if i am right what will be in HTML initially. will it be only `<table>` tag

Comment: you can consider "yes". basically table tag also generating dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though one.

```js
var data = {"data":"Start","nodes":[{"data":"All","nodes":[{"data":"Incident Management","nodes":[{"data":"Global","nodes":[{"data":"Bangalore","nodes":[{"data":"85.00%","nodes":[{"data":"90.00%","nodes":[{"data":"test","nodes":null}]}]},{"data":"90.00%","nodes":[{"data":"95.00%","nodes":[{"data":"test","nodes":null}]}]}]},{"data":"Frimley","nodes":[{"data":"85.00%","nodes":[{"data":"90.00%","nodes":[{"data":"test","nodes":null}]}]},{"data":"90.00%","nodes":[{"data":"95.00%","nodes":[{"data":"test","nodes":null}]}]}]},{"data":"Palo Alto","nodes":[{"data":"85.00%","nodes":[{"data":"90.00%","nodes":[{"data":"test","nodes":null}]}]},{"data":"90.00%","nodes":[{"data":"95.00%","nodes":[{"data":"test","nodes":null}]}]}]}]}]},{"data":"Service Availability","nodes":[{"data":"Global","nodes":[{"data":"N/A","nodes":[{"data":"85.00%","nodes":[{"data":"90.00%","nodes":[{"data":"","nodes":null}]}]}]}]}]}]}]}

function getNodeCount(obj){
 var num = 0
 if(obj.nodes){
  for(var i=0;i<obj.nodes.length;i++){
   num += getNodeCount(obj.nodes[i])
  }
 }else
  num = 1
 return num
}

function createRowHTML(data,html){
 if(html==null) html = '<tr>'
 html += '<td rowspan="'+getNodeCount(data)+'">'+data.data+'</td>'
 if(data.nodes){
  for(var i=0;i<data.nodes.length;i++){
   if(i==0)
    html += createRowHTML(data.nodes[i],'')
   else
    html += createRowHTML(data.nodes[i])
  }
 }else
  html += '</tr>'
 return html
}


var html = createRowHTML(data)



document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<table>'+html+'</table>'
```

```css
table td{
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```